# C program - scan for int and print the quotient of both ints as a float. Print the ints

Tags: c

> Write a C program that takes in two arguments from the user and stores them as integers. Print the quotient of the two integers as a float. Print the two arguments themselves as integers.  Constraints: You can only declare two variables `int var1, var2;` and you CANNOT use type casting. You must use the string formatting to cast the types. For example in `printf("%lf", somefloat)` the `%f` takes a float and returns a double.
>
> Again: Only two variables. Print quotient as float, print variables as integers.

Something like this - without type casting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int v1 = 0;
  int v2 = 0;
  scanf("%d %d", &v1, &v2);
  printf("qot %d %d %f", v1, v2, (float) v1 / v2); // NO TYPE CASTING !!!
}
```

Comment: `1.0 * v1 / v2`? or implement IEEE754. Or use `printf("%d.%03d\n", v1/v2, (v1 * 1000 + 500) / v2);`

Comment: Whenever you're given an exercise, think to yourself: **Would an employer in the real world expect you to solve this?** The constraints here are stupid... What your professor is teaching you to do is solve this problem in a stupid way. **Get a new professor and stop bothering us with these useless questions.**

Answer (score 4):

Is this OK?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int var1, var2;
    scanf("%d %d", &var1, &var2);
    printf("qot %d %d %f", var1, var2, 1.0f * var1 / var2); // implicit conversion
}
```

I also noticed "You must use the string formatting to cast the types" in your question. What do you mean by saying that?

Comment: Thank you this was bothering me.

Comment: Nitpicking: There is no such thing as "*implicit cast*". Casts are always explicit, by definition. You probably mean "implicit conversion".

Comment: Indeed. A cast is an explicit conversion; what you have here is an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int v1 = 0;
int v2 = 0;
scanf("%d %d", &v1, &v2);
printf("qot %d %d %f", v1, v2, ( 1.0 * v1 / v2)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a compound:

```
printf("%f", ((double){v1})/v2);
```

Comment: No, it's just a type definition, defining the the compound's type. @DonClaudio

Answer (score -2):

You can store the answer in an intermediate `float`, in spite of the restrictions on variables, by using a compound literal such as `(float){v1}`.

The notation introduced here seems suspiciously cast-like, but this is *not a cast*. The curly braces distinguish it from casts; the expression inside the curly braces forms an initialiser for an anonymous object.

We can objectively prove that `(float){v1}` isn't a cast; by observing [footnote 99](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note99) of [the section on compound literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5) it becomes clear that casts don't form lvalues and compound literals do. We can't modify the results of casts, though we can modify the results of compound literals:

```
((float) v1 ) = 42; // ERROR!   (float) v1  isn't an lvalue.
((float){v1}) = 42; // SUCCESS! (float){v1} is    an lvalue.
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't for answering homework questions without understanding. Anyway I got punished for wasting my time with a downvote. This is why I don't bother here anymore.

Comment: "*intermediate float*" as per the OP: "*You can only declare two variables ` int var1, var2;`*"

Comment: @alk "intermediate float" can be accomplished without introducing an extra variable.

Comment: @Seb: Using a function or a compound, yes. Everything else I'd call "type conversion".

Comment: @alk Don't you think such a function would make use of "type conversion"? Not all forms of type conversion are excluded by the specifications of the exercise.

Comment: @Sammy Please consider reopening this answer; I've added some useful tidbits to it, and I don't think you'll get any more negative votes now.

Comment: Yep I missed the requirement of only 2 variables. Agree 1.0f * .... is the way to solve this rather artificial problem.

Comment: Sorry  @Sammy bro your answer was really good I checked out the documentation you sent thanks bro... :|